# Change part of the filename on multiple files in a directory:

Tags: rename

I once had a script that would do the following. It would rename part of a filename of multiple files in the current directory:

For example:

```
rename variable1 variable2

rename 456 555
```

Input:

```
testa456testa
sama456sama
apple456applea
johna_456_johna
davida_456_davidb
```

Output:

```
testa555testa
sama555sama
apple555applea
johna_555_johna
davida_555_davidb
```

I don't have the script anymore, and I am still new to Unix.
I need a script, that I can use from the command line.

What I do now is:

I list the files "ls * (file names)" to a temp file name. Then I do a search %/s/456/555/g. Then I move all old file names, to new file names. I was able to do this in a command line "rename $1 to $2". So, in any given directory I would line to rename middle of file names from a command line. It could be hundreds of files. Hope this make sense, Thanks  Ivan

Comment: What's the question? Do you want help writing a script? Finding it? Making use of alternatives? Solving this specific problem of changing `456` to `555`? Please [edit your text to include a question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/316038/edit). And while you're there please tell us your UNIX flavour or Linux distribution.

Comment: yes, i need a script that i can used from the command line.  I am still new to Unix.   What i do is "ls  * (file names)" to a temp file name. then do  a search  %/s/456/555/g. then move all old file names to new file names.   I was able to do this in a command  line  "rename $1 to $2".   So, in any given directory i would line to rename middle of file names.  It could be hundred of files.   Hope this make sense,   Thanks.

Comment: What UNIX flavour or Linux distribution are you using? Is there any particular reason why you haven't installed the missing `rename` script?

Answer (score 8):

With only shell, using parameter expansion:

```
for f in *456*; do echo mv -i -- "$f" "${f//456/555}"; done
```

here we re iterating over the files having `456` in their names, and the parameter expansion pattern `${f//456/555}` will replace all `456` substrings in the filename with `555`.

The above will do the dry-run by showing what `mv` command will be run, you can remove `echo` to let the action take place:

```
for f in *456*; do mv -i -- "$f" "${f//456/555}"; done
```

---

With `rename` (`prename`):

```
rename -n 's/456/555/g' *456*
```

this will replace all (`g`) `456` substring from filenames with `555` (`s/456/555/`).

`-n` will do the dry-run, if you are satisfied with the changes to be made, remove `-n` to let the actual renaming take place:

```
rename 's/456/555/g' *456*
```

Comment: Why did you put "--" after the -i on this part: "mv -i --"?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're forgetting to pass the files to `rename`.

```
rename 456 555 *456*
```

Comment: The OP said they no longer had `rename`, so suggesting they use `rename` (of any flavour) doesn't seem particularly helpful.

Comment: @roaima it sounds like he had a script that used `rename` and he forgot how to use `rename`, not that he doesn't have `rename` at all.

Comment: Mmmm. Not convinced but given the poor question I'll go with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
which -a rename
```

Will tell you if any rename tools are on your $PATH.

```
rename 's/456/555/g' *
```

Is the preferred syntax for doing what you want (As stated in the [manual](http://man.he.net/man1/rename)). If you have no or an old version of rename without regex just [download](https://gist.github.com/javiermon/3939556) ([official](http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/rename/rename_0.20-4_all.deb)) prename Which is a `perl` script debian like systems use.

Comment: The OP said they no longer had `rename`, so suggesting they use `rename` (of any flavour) doesn't seem particularly helpful.

Comment: @roaina the OP is using rename wrong resulting in no action. Likely 'which rename' exists. Also if the OP really is missing it I informed him how to get it.

Comment: Mmm ok. Perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(Moved from a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348209/renames-a-set-of-files-that-contain-a-particular-search-string-to-file-names-tha) intended as an answer here)</sub>

I have found the answer to my question:

```
#! /bin/csh -f
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Script Name: moveme                          Date:   05/07/96
#  Written by:  John W. Woolsey                 Rev:    10/11/99
#
#  Description:
#    Renames a set of files that contain a particular search string
#    to file names that contain a replacement string.
#
#  Syntax:  moveme <search_string> <replace_string>
#
#  Where:
#     <search_string> is the name of the file name search string.
#     <replace_string> is the name of the file name replace string.
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
onintr catch
if ($#argv != 2) goto syntax

ls -d *$1* | sed "s/\(.*\)\$1\(.*\)/mv & \1$2\2/" | sh
exit 0

syntax:
echo "Syntax:  `basename $0` <search_string> <replace_string>"
exit 1

catch:
echo "`basename $0` was interrupted or terminated abnormally."
exit 1
```

Comment: Huh, a `csh` script that generate `sh` code...